# Ideal in a matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, p-adic-number-theory, noncommutative-algebra

**Edit** As Kimball point out, in the following question for me an ideal $I$ is a full $\mathbb{Z_p}$-lattice of $M_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ such that 
$$\lbrace\alpha \in M_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)\vert \alpha I \subset I \rbrace=M_2(\mathbb{Z}_P). $$

Let $p$ be a prime number and consider the ring, formed by the elements

$$  \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ pc & d   \end{pmatrix}$$

with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. Is it true that its ideals are generated by the elements

$$ \begin{pmatrix} p^n & 0 \\ pc & p^m   \end{pmatrix}$$

with $m,n$ integer and $c \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ a representative of the element $\bar c \in \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$?

How can you compute this?

It is well known that the ideals of $M_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ are generated by the elements

$$ \begin{pmatrix} p^n & r \\ 0 & p^m   \end{pmatrix}$$

with $r \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ a representative of the element $\bar c \in \mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z}$, and to do this it is enough look  suitable $\mathbb{Z}_p$-lattices $L,M$ of a $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector space $V$. Can I do something similar using my matrix ring?

Comment: Where $\mathbb Z_p$ is...?

Comment: $p$-adic integers, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the "It is well known..." sentence in your question.  For ideals in non-commutative rings, you need to differentiate between left and right ideals.  Let $R$ be a ring and $M = M_n(R)$.  Then a left ideal in $M$ is left $M$-submodule of $M$ itself.  The simple submodules of $M$ are the ideals $\mathcal I_j$ for $1 \le j \le n$ consisting of the elements of $M$ which are zero off the $j$-th column.  (I don't remember off the top of my head whether one need some conditions on $R$ for this, but at least for any $R$ these are ideals.)

A similar argument gives you ideals not generated by the elements you write down for your subring of $M_2(\mathbb Z_p)$.

Comment: I have exceeded with the sentence you are right. And I have to edit because I am referring to integral ideal of $M_2(R)$.  You can find a proof of this in theorem 6.5.3 pag 211 of The arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-manifolds of Maclachlan, Reid.

Comment: @user262440 You need to assume something like your ideals are invertible or normal (full lattices) for that to be true.  Integrality is not a sufficient condition.

Comment: You are completely right, I usually don't work with lattices that aren't full. I have edited the question.